# Audio crackle when using Multi-Output Device (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, audacity

(It's my first post on this forum, please edit this Q if necessary.)

I have recently obtained a copy of Ableton Live + a Launchpad, which I am using to record covers of songs. After a bit of googling around I found the best method for recording audio was to use Audacity + use Audio MIDI setup to create a Multi-Output device in order to send audio to both my (bluetooth) headphones + SoundFlower (64 channel) in order to both listen to + record my performance at once.
However, once I played back the audio I could hear a crackling noise that grew in volume the louder and further into the track I went.

This is a problem as (due to how I've set up some Live Sets that I want to record) I can find no other way to record this audio.

I have tried various other fixes - eg: I downloaded OBS and tried to record through that, but although the audio played fine I could not listen to the performance while recording.
I also tried using Hardware/Software play-through in Audacity, but there was a slight latency between triggering a sample in Live and hearing it through Audacity.

So, SoundFlower doesn't appear to be causing the issue, although the crackle only seems to be created in that output.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I've spent several hours trawling the internet for fixes, and while others have reported this problem - no-one has offered an answer.

Many thanks for any help or work-arounds people can offer.

Comment: I distrust Bluetooth headphones so much, I want to know if the same problem happens when you use wired headphones.

Comment: @Spiff I tested with the built in speakers and got the same problem - I can see the distrust with bluetooth speakers, but I'm fairly sure they aren't causing the problem this time

Comment: I don't really know the specific software [Ableton/Audacity] but it kind of 'feels' like a buffer underrun; simply can't keep up, latency is set too low. I'd test at higher buffer sizes, though I'd also be tempted to try something other than Soundflower to route the audio. Rogue Amoeba do [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) & also Loopback [neither cheap, but both very good]. Might be worth checking out a demo.

Comment: Audio Hijack looks perfect - I'm not intending on routing audio for longer than 10 minutes at a time so the free version looks fine. I can definitely seem myself purchasing them both in the future though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Record directly into Ableton Live.  Set your track monitoring to IN or AUTO if the track is armed, then use the headphone jack to monitor.  Using Soundflower 2CH as your system's output allows you to use Soundflower 2CH as your Ableton Input.

You don't need Audacity to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old thread, I still suffered terrible crackling and popping noises with Soundflower, mostly when streaming online content such as YouTube or SoundCloud.

I just spent a couple of days messing around with different configurations and I found that changing the Audio Format settings in Audio Devices from 44.1KHz to 48KHz solved it for both Input and Output in Soundflower (2ch) or (64ch) depending which one you're using. I now have perfect Audio quality.

I use a Focusrite Scarlet II USB audio interface with Harman Kardon Soundticks.